# Date-obj not compared right

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with this simple code. I wonder why the second element (Two) is not removed? The Date: `2014, 11, 06` should already be expired, right?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slottybon/68tL6uz7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="dates">
    <p class="2014, 12, 05">One</p>
    <p class="2014, 11, 06">Two</p>
    <p class="2015, 01, 20">Three</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var current = new Date(),
        elements = document.getElementById("dates").children,
        deleteDate = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        deleteDate = new Date(elements[i].className);

        if (current > deleteDate) {
            elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
        }
    }
```

I really do not know why this is happening ...

Comment: [`children()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) returns a __live__ [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in your loop, we we start at `i = 0`.
2. Index `0` is the `One` element.
3. `One` is removed
4. Next loop iteration, `i = 1`.
5. Index `1` is now the `Three` element because the first was removed in the last loop.

So `Two` is skipped entirely.

You should save the elements you want to remove and then remove them all at once instead.

Answer (score 0):

is this what youre looking for?  demo: http://jsfiddle.net/68tL6uz7/2/

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var dateList = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i =0; i < dateList.length; i++) {
    console.log(dateList[i]);
    var text = dateList[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
    var newDate = new Date(text);
    console.log(newDate);
    if (currentDate > newDate) {
        dateList[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

<div id="dates">
    <p class="">2014, 12, 05</p>
    <p class="">2014, 11, 06</p>
    <p class="">2015, 01, 20</p>
</div>
```